# background-image with parallax

Tags: jquery, html, css

So i need a section of a website to have parallax with a background image. The problem is that the code calculate the parallax from the beginning of the website (it is a long scroll-down type website) and when i reach the mentioned section, the background is already too far up. Would need some kind of "delay" in the code so the parallax begin after a X-number of pixel scrolled? here the code:

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Cache the Window object
    $window = $(window);

    $('section[data-type="background"]').each(function() {
        var $bgobj = $(this); // assigning the object

        $(window).scroll(function() {

            // Scroll the background at var speed
            // the yPos is a negative value because we're scrolling it UP!                              
            var yPos = -($window.scrollTop() / $bgobj.data('speed'));

            // Put together our final background position
            var coords = '50% ' + yPos + 'px';

            // Move the background
            $bgobj.css({
                backgroundPosition: coords
            });
        }); // window scroll Ends
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<section id="background" data-type="background" data-speed="5">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="shadow-block"><img src="images/shadow-b.png" alt="" class="scale-with-grid"/></div>
            <div class="quote two-thirds column" >  
            </div>
            </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
#background {
    background: url(../images/big-bg.jpg)no-repeat center center;
    background-size:cover;
    width: 100%;
    height:500px;
    padding: 40px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you not do something like this?

```
var Top = $(document).scrollTop();
    if(Top < 200){ 
    //Then do the parallax stuff...
}
```

Comment: i bet he's from some web agency & trying to get for free what he should be paying a developper for - in which case he cannot do much - ie the code is clean, seems obvious he didn't write it

Comment: na am not from an agency.. am just new to jquery

Comment: @BeatAlex didn't work, or maybe i integrated that code in the wrong way? how would you put all together?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use "background-size:cover" css property and take care of one thing that your background images should be large than the size of the each viewport and lastly scroll speed should be in descending fashion, means that first slide should have more scroll speed than second slide.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the parallax effect just when the element is shown on the screen:

```
if (($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) > elementPositionTop) {
   //
}
```

I think that would be enough.